# Spring MVC 4.0.1 Request Mapping Not work

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I new to Spring MVC, tried Various Examples but didn't work
I used NetBEan IDE 8.2
Spring 4.0.1
Java 1.8 And
Apache Tomcat 8.0.27

Here My Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

My Dispath-servelet.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers" />


    <bean id="viewResolver" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" 
      value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

And Controller

```
package com.controllers.admin;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    public AdminController(){
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(){

     return "hello";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashbord", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dashbord (){

        return "dashbord";
    }
}
```

When I navigate to http://localhost:8084/PropertySales/admin 
It says 404 The requested resource is not available.

And I check the server log I found This

```
WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-202] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/PropertySales/admin/dashbord] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

What the wrong In My Code. Can someone help

Comment: If you have the option, my advice to you is to start with [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) and then you don't need the XML.

Comment: see my answer I think that will fix it. Also that is better than spring boot - you will learn a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.xml`, you did not provide the `dispath-servelet.xml` as the `contextConfigLocation`, so add it as shown below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispath-servelet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Spring would have complain earlier if context configuration file was not found. I think the problem is different than this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add these to your dispatcher servlet as you have changed the name:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-properties.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Comment: Spring would have complain earlier if context configuration file was not found. I think the problem is different than this.

Comment: thank for the answer.. but it's bring another error
" Could not open ServletContext resource "

Answer (score 0):

Can you try modifying the web.xml entry for servlet-mapping to what is below and check?

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then use http://localhost:8084/PropertySales/admin/dashbord.htm ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution my self

the Issue is the "applicationContext.xml" file
what ever configurations put in the "dispatch-servlet.xml", should include in the  "applicationContext.xml"

Here my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers" />


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And Dispatch-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers" />


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```